# How should I go about checking if my graph has at least X Minimum Spanning Trees?

Tags: algorithm, graph, minimum-spanning-tree

I am looking for an efficient algorithm for finding if at least 'X' number of MST exist in a graph. Any pointers?

Comment: What do you mean by that? Example? What have you tried?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This doesn't flesh out a full algorithm, but the accepted answer to [An algorithm to see if there are exactly two MSTs in a graph?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13751582/an-algorithm-to-see-if-there-are-exactly-two-msts-in-a-graph) (by @j_random_hacker) brings up a point that will probably help you a lot. Taken from his answer:

> Furthermore, *every* MST can be produced by choosing some particular way
>   to order every set of equal-weight edges, and then running the Kruskal
>   algorithm.

<del>You could probably write up an algorithm that takes advantage of this to get the number of MSTs.</del> Well, just straight using this fact and nothing else probably doesn't get to "efficient algorithm" territory, though I imagine that any efficient algorithm is going to be taking advantage of a couple of similar facts. I'll add more results if I find any.